# Redirection to taxonomy posts list after post submit.

Tags: posts, taxonomy, wp-list-table

I am able to redirect the user back to the edit.php admin page after they have successfully created/updated a post.

However, is it possible to redirect them to the taxonomy term posts page? This way, when a user creates a post, they will be redirected to the admin post list page that only shows that post and others with the same taxonomy term.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that a post can have more than one category, also posts can have no category, what you'll do in that cases?

And what about post update?

That said, if you look at the url when in `edit.php` and select a category by clicking on its name, you'll notice that the only thing that change in the url is that the param `category_name` is appended to url.
You can easily do that by get the category using [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) and appending the url argument using [`add_query_arg`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg).

I'm assuming that:

- if post has more than one category, use the first one.
- if the post has no category, redirect to `edit.php` without any category filter.
- if the post status is 'draft' does not trigger the redirect.
- if the post is deleted, redirect to trash.
- if the post is updated you will act in the same way

So:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', function( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
  if ( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ) return;
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
  if ( $post->post_type !== 'post' ) return;
  if ( in_array($post->post_status, array('draft','auto-draft','inherit') ) ) return;
  $url = add_query_arg( array( 'post_type'=>'post' ), admin_url('edit.php') );
  if ( $post->post_status === 'trash' ) {
    $args = array('post_status' => 'trash', 'trashed' => '1', 'ids' => $post_ID );
    $redirect = add_query_arg( $args, $url );
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect );
    exit();
  }
  $url = add_query_arg( array( 'pid' => $post_ID ), $url );
  // uncomment following line to avoid redirect on post update
  // if ($update) return;
  $cats = get_the_category( $post_ID );
  if ( empty( $cats ) ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( $url );
    exit();
  }
  $cat = array_shift( $cats );
  $args = array( 'category_name' => $cat->slug, 'msg' => 'updated' );
  $redirect = add_query_arg( $args, $url );
  wp_safe_redirect( $redirect );
  exit();

}, PHP_INT_MAX, 3);
```

I've used `'wp_insert_post'` with the highest priority because it's the last hook fired when a post is saved. In this way code for saving custom metaboxes, that normally runs on `save_post`, should work with no problems because that hook is fired first.

However, the issues with this are:

- you don't see the "post updated" message anymore
- when, after redirect, you show only one category in `edit.php` the filter is not very evident at first glance and this can confuse users

For these reasons, I want to share a way to proper show messages making the edit page more clear after redirect:

```
add_action('admin_notices', function() {
  $screen = get_current_screen();
  if ( $screen->id !== 'edit-post' ) return; 
  $pid = (int) filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'pid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
  if ( ! $pid > 0 ) return;
  $msg = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'msg', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
  if ( $msg === 'updated' ) {
    echo '<div class="updated"><p>';
    printf(
      __('Post updated. <a href="%s">View post</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($pid) )
    );
    echo '</p></div>';
  }
  $cat = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'category_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
  if( ! empty($cat) ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $cat, 'category' );
    if ( empty( $term ) ) return;
    $c = get_taxonomy( 'category' );
    $cname = esc_html( $c->labels->singular_name );
    echo '<div class="updated"><p>';
    $all = add_query_arg( array( 'post_type'=>'post' ), admin_url('edit.php') );
    $f = '%s <strong>&quot;%s&quot;</strong>. <a href="%s">%s</a>';
    printf( $f, $cname, esc_html($term->name), esc_url($all), __('All Posts') );
    echo '</p></div>';
  }
});
```